# Reading Special MouseButtons

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, mouse-buttons

I am interested in capturing input from the explorer mouse buttons (the special buttons on the side of mice normally used to go forward and back on web browsers).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class MouseThing extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        pane.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)
                out.println("LEFT"); 
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
                out.println("RIGHT");      
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE)
                out.println("MIDDLE");    
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.NONE)
                out.println("OTHER");  
            // How read explorer buttons?  
            out.println("click");
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 100);
        stage.setTitle("Demo");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Just for the example, I would like to record that the advance and retreat buttons were activated.  The only interaction I can achieve at this point is left, right and middle clicks.  Pressing the `forward` and `back` buttons on the mouse doesn't even register the `click` print.

There was this post for Javascript: [JS special mouse buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906619/js-special-mouse-buttons), but it wasn't useful for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaFX 12, the [forward](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseButton.html#FORWARD) and [back](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseButton.html#BACK) buttons on the mouse are recognized, so you can do:

```
pane.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)
        out.println("LEFT");
    if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
        out.println("RIGHT");
    if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE)
        out.println("MIDDLE");
    if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.BACK)
        out.println("BACK");
    if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.FORWARD)
        out.println("FORWARD");
    if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.NONE)
        out.println("NONE");  
    out.println("click");
});
```